# Where query with "internal relation" of the searched object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to use sequelize in order to produce simple query, kind of:

```
SELECT * FROM `Products`
WHERE `Product`.`oldPrice` > `Product`.`newPrice`
```

At the moment I do kind of ugly raw query, like:

```
database.Product.find({ where: '`Product`.`oldPrice` > `Product`.`newPrice`' })
```

It is not really bad practice or something, but I wonder whether I have not missed a paragraph amidst the documentation which would introduce me to a cleaner form, like for example mongo function expression (see: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-%24where).

```
database.Product.find({ where: function () {
    return (this.oldPrice > this.newPrice);
});
```

Is there a shortcut of such kind, or will I have to keep on writing SQL in such cases?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Product.find({
    where: {
        oldPrice: {
            gt: sequelize.col('newPrice')
        }
    }
});
```